# How can I add a better platform Algorithm to my game?

Tags: java, 2d

(Java code)

Ever heard of Doodle Jump? If so, I'm trying to mimic the way they do their platforms. (Endless runner style)
they seem so evenly spread out even with the monsters and blackholes they have within the game. Currently this is what my layout for adding platforms looks like and something just seems off about it. If someone could please help me with a better way.

```
public void addNewPlatform() {
    int platformAmount[] = new int[500];
    for (int i = 0; i < platformAmount.length; i++) {
        int x = (int) (platformAmount[i] + 400 * Math.random());
        int y = -i * 64;
        handler.object.add(new Platform(Id.plank, x, y, ss, random.nextInt(4), handler));
        System.out.println("count of pads " + y);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "If someone could please help me with a better way." you need to define in what way it needs to be better (or, alternatively, in what way it currently isn't good enough).

Comment: A better formula for the platforms, endless runners that I have seen seem to be in some type of order, but it’s still random. Mine just seems to be a bit cluttered and doesn’t feel like an actual game that’s playable.